# How to convert HTML to PDF in Spring MVC using Netbeans

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to create a PDF to generate reports.

I was using iReport but I find one drawback is that you can't manipulate the data as it is taken directly from the database.

Is there another way to make a PDF in Spring MVC using Netbeans?

Most of the tutorials i find are meant for Eclipse.

Comment: What’s the relevance of your IDE here? Why can’t you use the tutorials meant for Eclipse?

Comment: Actually, what is the relevance of Spring MVC in this context? Spring MVC drives your web application, but actually has no relation to either HTML or PDF.

Comment: Yes the ide does not matter, but am still new to Spring MVC. In eclipse its just abit different , m still abot confused

Comment: In what way do you need to 'manipulate the data' that iReport won't allow?

Comment: In one of my table i am concatenating two or more data into one field, so now i need to split them and display them individually. Also i need to do some if statement on them